Would well-founded Scott cardinals work in ZCA + Ranks?
Does original Zermelo's set theory + Regularity + Ranks, prove that every set is of equal size to some element of a Scott cardinal? The original Zermelo does include an axiom of Choice, and it admits urelements. To be noticed is that a Scott cardinal is a well-founded set.
